# Git SmartHttp : Where is git-http-backend.exe?

Tags: windows, git, apache

I'm trying to configure a git server in mode "SmartHTTP" following the instructions.

https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-on-the-Server-Smart-HTTP

It might seems dumb a bit but I can't seem to find the file `git-http-backend.exe`. I'm stuck at this part

```
SetEnv GIT_PROJECT_ROOT /opt/git
SetEnv GIT_HTTP_EXPORT_ALL
ScriptAlias /git/ /usr/lib/git-core/git-http-backend/
```

I'm brand new to apache configuration but I interpret this part as "You need to tell apache where the `git-http-backend.exe` file is to it will use it to handle all the requests in the `/git/` folder."

The problem is that I don't find this file... I installed git for Windows 64-bit from [this page](http://git-scm.com/download/win) and this file is no where in my git installation directory.

Answer (score 4):

Found it...

```
C:\Program Files\Git\mingw64\libexec\git-core\git-http-backend.exe
```